# how to improve mysql query performance ?

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query but it taking 10 sec to return data....how should i improve it...?

```
select `vw_org_products`.*, 
(CASE WHEN prod_status_code = 'SELL' THEN 1000 ELSE
        (select count(1) from org_product_prices
           where org_product_id = vw_org_products.id
           and base_price>0 and deleted_at is null
          and prod_status_code = 'SELL' 
          and price_date = (select max(p2.price_date)
                                                                                from org_product_prices p2
                                                                               where p2.deleted_at is null
                                                                                 and p2.num_units = org_product_prices.num_units
                                                                                 and p2.org_product_id = org_product_prices.org_product_id
                                                                                 and p2.sell_organisation_id = org_product_prices.sell_organisation_id)
                                                            )
                                                        END) as base_sort_rank, (select count(access_key) from access_history
                                                                                where vw_org_products.id = access_history.access_key
                                                                                and access_history.created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
                                                                                and access_history.access_type = "OrgProduct.View"
                                                                                and access_history.product_id = vw_org_products.product_id 
                                                                                GROUP BY  access_history.product_id) as views from `vw_org_products` 
                                                                                where `vw_org_products`.`deleted_at` is null and `vw_org_products`.`product_id` = "1" 
                                                                                and `prod_status_code` in ("COMINGSOON","MFG_DISCONTINUED","OUTOFSTOCK","PREBOOK","SELL") 
                                                                                order by `base_sort_rank` desc, `views` desc, `updated_at` desc limit 1
```

Thanks !

Comment: if you could provide us with some example cases (tables) so people can execute it in their own environment it's a lot easier to help. Also you can try yourself, add EXPLAIN in front of the select to see how the query works. Maybe find a database editor that show you the execution time. (I use HeidiSQL which does that)

Comment: actually it selects whole vw_org_products table and add two additional columns i.e. base_sort_rank and views, based on those two columns the products will show to the users.

Comment: can i write query in a different way specially cases part.